# ¿Cómo comprobar si mi interfaz está en modo monitor?

Tags: linux, bash, debian

Me gustaría hacer un script que compruebe si mi interfaz wifi está en modo monitor y que devuelva 1 si está en modo monitor y 0 si no

Comment: ¿Qué intentaste?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El comando iwconfig retorna esto:

```
wlx002586e7a108  IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"home"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: C8:BE:19:8C:38:42   
          Bit Rate=54 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=53/100  Signal level=53/100  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:895  Invalid misc:97463   Missed beacon:0
```

La información requerida está en la segunda línea. En este caso, el modo es *Managed*.

Usaremos grep para buscar el texto "Mode:Monitor" en la salida de `iwconfig`. Si lo encontramos, significa que si está en modo Monitor.

**monitor.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# Uso: monitor.sh WIFI_interface
#
linea=$(/sbin/iwconfig $1|grep Mode:Monitor)
if [ -n "$linea" ]; then
   exit 0
else
   exit 1
fi
```

Forma de uso:

```
monitor.sh nombre_interface_wifi
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!